# JQuery add Checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am currently experimenting with the google chart api and jquery. I don't have any problems with the google chart api so far, however i have not been able to get jquery working. What I want to do is I want to loop over my json objects I got and add Checkboxes depending on what I get out of the json.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load Google JSAPI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
addSensorCheckboxes();

        function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "getValues.php",
                data: window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1),
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);

            var options = {
                title: ''
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
                                    document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

        function addSensorCheckboxes() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "getSensors.php",
                async: false
            }).responseText;

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);

            for (i in obj)
            {
                var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="sensors[]" value="'+obj[i][0]+'" />'+obj[i][1];
                //alert(checkbox);
                $("#test").append(checkbox);
            }

        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="theForm" name="theForm" action="index.php" method="get">
    <span id="test"></span>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
</form>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any specific mistake I made?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards

Germinator

Comment: What is error on console?

Comment: What is value of obj[i][0] ?

Comment: solved it by using $( document ).ready(addSensorCheckboxes); on the line where I first wanted to call the function

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
            var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" name="sensors[]" 
                                       value="'+obj[i][0]+'" />'+obj[i][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of possibilities. Make sure addSensorCheckboxes() is being called and that obj is populated. console.log() is the easiest way to figure out where the application is failing.

Fix your for-in loop as well....`for (var i in obj)` otherwise 'i' would be global.

Make sure var checkbox is a DOM element, HTML string, or jQuery object (as per the jquery documentation)

Comment: Still doesn't work. The objects are being populated correctly, I checked by alerting the string i create it says `<input type="checkbox" name="sensors[]" value="1" />Test` which should work .. shouldn't it?